# react-native build error (development server returned response error code: 500)

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to develop a new project with React Native. But I have little knowledge of React Native. I did all the setups correctly. But I can not build from emulator. Can you help me? I get an error like this:

```
The development server returned response error code: 500
```

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"originModulePath":"C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js","targetModuleName":"AccessibilityInfo","message":"Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\cenkd\\Desktop\\reactprojem\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\cenkd\\Desktop\\reactprojem\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\\Users\\cenkd\\Desktop\\reactprojem\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:167:1306)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:80:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:237:485)\n    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:116:25)\n    at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:298:29)\n    at Array.map ()\n    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:294:16)\n    at C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:159:33\n    at Generator.next ()\n    at step (C:\Users\cenkd\Desktop\reactprojem\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:239:307)"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:285
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:37
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:163
execute
    RealCall.java:153
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641
run
    Thread.java:764

[Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5CZK.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i had the same issue.

my previous react-native version was

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0
```

then i uninstall react-native

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
removed 41 packages in 3.999s
```

then i installed react-native version 0.55.4

```
npm install react-native@0.55.4
```

again intsalled reacnative cli 1.2.0

```
npm install -g react-native-cli@1.2.0
```

then this installation of creating react-native project work out

```
react-native init --version="0.55.4" myprojectname
```

Comment: So, the unique way to have it working is downgrading the RN version? No way with 0.56.0,  Thanks

Comment: is there any solution without downgrade version ?

Comment: dont know, have been creating project like that solution.

Comment: i have tried this solution it doesn't worked for me

Comment: @Vishali It is 3 yrs old solution for windows 10. Current latest react-native version is 66.0. follows the installation steps clearly from react native documentation site.

Comment: https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-react-native-on-windows-10/    i have followed this link for installation but it doesn't helped me

Comment: @RaikumarKhangembam i am facing the same error with current react-native-version

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug on version 0.56. so i suggest you to downgrade from 0.56 to version 0.55
just run this command

```
npm install react-native@0.55.4 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching and trying everything I can do to fix my react project; for me the solution that really worked is downgrade the react version.

My version was 0.59.2; I got an error 500 code message every time I tried to create a project with that version.

So this is my solution :

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

then you can install the previous version to 0.55.2

```
npm install react-native@0.55.2
```

and then run :

```
npm install -g react-native-cli@1.2.0
```

create a new project with previous version :

```
react-native init --version="0.55.2" yourProjectName
```

Answer (score -1):

This error also occurs from incorrectly typing file paths. You can also check file paths.