# react native The development server returned response error code 500

Tags: android, react-native

I newly installed Android SDK (
Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

- Google APIs
- Android SDK Platform 23
- Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image 23
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image 23
- Android SDK Platform 26
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image 26

) and NodeJS 8.11.3, JDK 8.0, Python 2.

I used genymotion simulator for run android app.

when i run the app ( react-native run-android ) it's start and show this error-

[image: error notification image]

i tried 2,3 times newly but got this error every time. how can i fix this?
why recent versions make this type errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native build error (development server returned response error code: 500)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333897/react-native-build-error-development-server-returned-response-error-code-500)

Comment: thank. i followed that link. but i need to know, what is the version problem? why is that happening? how can i fix thiss error without downgrade react-native versions?

Comment: How are you creating your react native project?

Comment: i followed react native - Building Projects with Native Code getting started doc (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content )

Comment: Can you please try with create-react-native-app tool.

Comment: i dont use expo app. i need to use CLI mood react-native.